# Python intercept stdout, listen to write on stream, capture stdout live

Tags: python, python-3.x, stream, tee

I want to capture stdout as it comes, to react every time it is written to. I've not been able to find anything like "io stream on-write listener" etc.

How can I redirect stdout live? at the moment I have

```py
import sys
import time

from io import IOBase, StringIO


class Tee:
    def __init__(self, target: IOBase):
        self._stdout = sys.stdout
        self.target = target

    def __enter__(self):
        sys.stdout = self.target

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        sys.stdout = self._stdout
        copy_here.seek(0)
        for line in copy_here.readlines():
            print(line, end='')
        copy_here.seek(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    copy_here = StringIO()
    with Tee(copy_here):
        print('one')
        print('two')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('three')
    print(copy_here.getvalue())
```

But this causes all the print outputs to be buffered until the context is exited, finally they are printed.

Rather I want the output to be printed to stdout as it comes, at the same time as being copied to the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I came up with the idea of making a wrapper stream around the actual target stream, that passes method calls on after intercepting them and printing them to stdout first.

This seems to work.

```py
import sys
import time

from io import IOBase, StringIO
from types import SimpleNamespace


class Tee:
    def __init__(self, target: IOBase):
        self._stdout = sys.stdout
        self.target = target
        self.wrapped_target = SimpleNamespace()
        for method in filter(lambda x: not x.startswith('_'), dir(sys.stdout)):
            setattr(self.wrapped_target, method, self._wrapped_method(method))

    def _wrapped_method(self, stdout_method):
        def wrapped_method(*args, **kwargs):
            getattr(self.target, stdout_method)(*args, **kwargs)
            return getattr(self._stdout, stdout_method)(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped_method


    def __enter__(self):
        sys.stdout = self.wrapped_target

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        sys.stdout = self._stdout


if __name__ == '__main__':
    copy_here = StringIO()
    with Tee(copy_here):
        print('one')
        print('two')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('three')
    print(copy_here.getvalue())
```

But it seems such overkill for a pretty simple problem.